# Aptana studio 3 gives me a java missing error?

Tags: java, aptana-studio

After [downloading aptana](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.2.2.201208201020/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.2.2.zip) en extracting it in my home folder
I run it like so

```
./AptanaStudio3
```

After that i get a box saying

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Aptana Studio 3. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/home/****/.Aptana_Studio_3/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH
```

I have never installed java on my ubuntu machines. i am currently running 12.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've installed aptana in my ubuntu too, you just need to run these commands:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update
```

to get the java repository and then use:

```bash
sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

to install Java jdk7.